# Programmatically Create Runner for BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Is it possible to programmatically create and register a runner in bitbucket pipelines, in other words without having to create it first via the BitBucket UI.

The docker command provided requires a runner UUID, which must be created when creating the runner through the UI. Is there a way to programmatically create it through the BitBucket API? It seems a bit backward to have to create the runner first just to get the UUID so you can then deploy it.

With GitHub Actions Self Hosted runners, a runner can be created and registered to GitHub using a temporary token, but it does not seem like BitBucket have a dopted this approach, at least yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing the Bitbucket API does not allow for this. There are two open feature requests for Bitbucket Runner APIs, [BCLOUD-21708](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-21708) and [BCLOUD-21309](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-21309), that may benefit from some votes.